# What to use for a 1-13 range changer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to build an app where the user will have to select a number from 1-13
Imagine the arrows here are buttons that increase and decrease the value:
 `< 1-13 >`
What would be the best layout code to use? Spinner number pick or just create 2 button and a textview and array to setText.
I will create this layout in relative table layout.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some xml code will help most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using two buttons.

```
//default number
int n = 1;

//Define the buttons and text
Button increase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIncrease);
Button decrease = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDecrease);
TextView numVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);

//Set the textView to the initial value
numVal.setText(Integer.toString(n));

//Button to increase the  number
increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
      if(n<13){ //Nothing will happen when the number reaches 13
         n = n+1;
         numVal.setText(Integer.toString(n));
      }
   }
   });

decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
      if(n>1){
         n = n-1;
         numVal.setText(Integer.toString(n));
      }
   }
   });
```